# How to pass column value in node js sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I need to pass the column value dynamically in node js sequelize but its not working properly

In attributes section..

attributes: ['id',"pollId","pollOption",[db.sequelize.literal("(SELECT count(id)*100/(SELECT count(id) from CM_Poll_Results where pollId =CM_Poll_Options.pollId) from CM_Poll_Results where choice =CM_Poll_Options.id )"),'percentageValue'],[db.sequelize.literal("(SELECT count(id) from CM_Poll_Results where pollId =CM_Poll_Options.pollId )"),'count']],

for the count field return correct but for percentageValue its return null.

Instead of CM_Poll_Options.pollId pass value 7 statically its working fine

i have used sub query

Answer (score 0):

```
attributes: ['id',"pollId","pollOption",[db.sequelize.literal(`(((SELECT COUNT(PR1.id) FROM CM_Poll_Results AS PR1 WHERE PR1.choice = CM_Poll_Options.id ) * 100) /(SELECT COUNT(PR2.id) FROM CM_Poll_Results AS PR2 WHERE PR2.pollId = CM_Poll_Options.pollId)) `),'percentageValue']],
```